# Bootstrap 4.5 How can I change container grid-gutter-width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

Under `_variables.scss` we can change `$grid-gutter-width: 30px !default;` for all components.

Now, I need to change it only for `.container` class:

Like:

```
.container {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Where I can manage this on BS 4.5?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. Are you looking to only change the gutter (padding) for rows/cols inside the `.container` class and *not* `.container-fluid`? ... OR are you looking to change it only on the container itself (and not the grid columns)?

Comment: @Zim yes.. only for class container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `.container` only...

```
.container {
   @include make-container(40px);
}
```

For the `.container` and the grid columns inside it...

```
.container {
   @include make-container(40px);
   @include make-grid-columns($grid-columns, 40px, $grid-breakpoints)
}
```

[Codeply demo](https://codeply.com/p/ua1Ea6r5IK)

Comment: Great..! I just added `80px` to get `40px` padding for left & right sides..